# Orchard Setting theme dynamically

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'm setting a theme dynamically in Orchard using `ISiteThemeService` Service :

```
_themeManager.SetSiteTheme("MyTheme");
```

but for some reason the theme (The  Theme MAchine) is still activated with no stylesheet in it .

EDIT : when i restart Orchard the theme was successfully activated .

does this means i have to restart Orchard every time a set up a theme to be the current theme ?

if so how can i do it dynamically ? (restating Orchard) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct interface to implement is probably `IThemeSelector` (see https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/6720b71cf3474a9a7b8a8cc9a99d58b1e733acfa/src/Orchard/Themes/IThemeSelector.cs).

The role of `ThemeService` is to manage what themes are available, but it is implementations of `IThemeSelector` that determine which theme to use for each request.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to inject `IThemeService` and call:

```
_themeService.EnableThemeFeatures("MyTheme");
```

---

As an aside, the general theme of your questions here on SO and GitHub suggest you are doing a lot of automatic set up of tenants, you may want to look at [Recipes](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Making-a-Web-Site-Recipe/).

Comment: I also tried to inject the ThemeService and Enable then Apply the theme but it still does not work . i still need to restart the application .

Comment: Are there any errors? Where is your code running? Would be helpful to see some more code too